Grow id: kyydone, IP :192.168.1.2 , Indonesia, East Kalimantan Province, Tenggarong city opposite Loa Lepu village
Continuous connection errors occur in the Growtopia game.
Repair and Repair and know why I keep getting connection errors So that I can play normally again, I really want to play the Growtopia game, so please immediately investigate what is causing me to not be able to log in/connection error.
